# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS freezing randomly

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, desktop-environments, freeze

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 but lately it freezes randomly and the panel icons disappear including the power button, the launcher does not show, search also does not work and when I click any file on desktop, they turn white until I shutdown forcefully. May anyone help please.
The first image is how desktop files change and the second inage is the only thing left on the panel.

I use Lenovo G50-80 model 80L0

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you [edit] the question and add some hardware configuration info.

Comment: @Shashanth , I've edited the quiz please check